# Preference of interpersonal commandments?

Tags: quran, allah

In Judaism there is a notion (with qualifications) that interpersonal commandments take preference over those commandments which are between man and God.

Is there a similar notion in Islam? I would appreciate sources which address this topic from anywhere, such as Hadith, Quran, modern thinkers, etc.

Comment: Thanks, do you have the sources?

Comment: There are some quotes according to which Allah my forgive any sin we may commit, except those we have harmed other people! What came to mind is in [sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/45/77) , [sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/46/10) and [al-Adab al-Mufrad](http://sunnah.com/adab/42/6) ... Also relevant [How reliable is the quote 70 sins between you and Allah is much lighter than one sin between you and the people](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46473/how-reliable-is-the-quote-70-sins-between-you-and-allah-is-much-lighter-than)